# Define a recursive function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to Define a recursive function is-bst : EBT(N) → Bool in such a
way that is-bst(t) = true if, and only if, t is a binary search tree.

Comment: What is "EBT(N)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know a way
to traverse a tree?
There are more than one.

If your definition of
a binary tree
is a tree that has at most two leaves
at each node,
then
traverse the tree
and check each node
for the number of leaves.
If the number is more than two,
fail.
If all node have at most
two leaves, succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution
$$\operatorname{isBST}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mbox{true},&x\lt0\\
\mbox{false},&\operatorname{prev}(x)\ge0\land\operatorname{value}(x)\le\operatorname{value}(\operatorname{prev}(x))\\
\mbox{false},&\operatorname{next}(x)\ge0\land\operatorname{value}(x)\ge\operatorname{value}(\operatorname{next}(x))\\
\operatorname{isBST}(\operatorname{prev}(x))\land\operatorname{isBST}(\operatorname{next}(x)),&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$